# Whatsapp group message erro

Tags: whatsapp

my python :
Package            Version

---

chromedriver       2.24.1
pandas             2.2.0
selenium           4.17.2
webdriver-manager  4.0.1

i have this code ....

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/rockie/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

name = input('Enter the name of user or group: ')

msg = input('Enter your message: ')

count = int(input('Enter the count: '))

input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')

try:

```
# Wait until the user element is visible

user = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//span[@title="{name}"]')))

user.click()

# Wait until the message box element is visible

msg_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_1Plpp')))

for i in range(count):

    msg_box.send_keys(msg)

    # Wait until the send button element is visible

    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_35EW6')))

    button.click()
```

finally:

```
driver.quit()
```

and this error ....

C:\Users\pacto\Desktop\Prog_zap_02> & C:/Users/pacto/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/pacto/Desktop/Prog_zap_02/whats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 87, in driver_location
browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\pacto\Desktop\Prog_zap_02\whats.py", line 6, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/rockie/Downloads/chromedriver')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 49, in **init**
PS C:\Users\pacto\Desktop\Prog_zap_02> & C:/Users/pacto/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/pacto/Desktop/Prog_zap_02/whats.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 87, in driver_location
browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\pacto\Desktop\Prog_zap_02\whats.py", line 6, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/rockie/Downloads/chromedriver')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 49, in **init**
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\pacto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

is version ?????
thanks

I realized that the version that was written is older, but I can't find references about version 4, with WhatsApp, I need to send messages in groups, if anyone has any references I would appreciate it